# you owe me and you owe my

Tags: grammar, writing-style

I read all the answers about "owe" but I am still confused. My question is not about the meaning of sentences, it's clear but which grammar rule is used in these sentences:

- I owe you some money (and not I owe your money)
- You owe me some money (and not you owe my money)

are sentences on the left correct grammatically?

Comment: The sentences on the left are grammatical.

Comment: The only difference between the two sentences is who owes whom.

Comment: You cannot _owe_ what belongs to another party. Your debt is exclusively your own. And until you pay them back, they do not possess the thing owed, so it cannot be called theirs. The barrier of _possession_ firmly separates debtors and creditors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"owe" is usually a ditransitive verb: *somebody owes* ***somebody something***.

We can say things like:

- I owe a lot of money. (Here ,"owe" is monotransitive. In this case, the creditors are not specified.)

When the creditor is specified, then the ditransitive pattern is required:

- I owe **you / the bank** a lot of money.